# Understand the assembly code generated by a simple C program

Tags: c, linux, assembly, stack, disassembly

I am trying to understand the assembly level code for a simple C program by inspecting it with gdb's disassembler.

Following is the C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
  function(1,2,3);
}
```

Following is the disassembly code for both `main` and `function`

```
gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x08048428 <main+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048429 <main+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x0804842b <main+3>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
0x0804842e <main+6>:    sub    $0x10,%esp
0x08048431 <main+9>:    movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)
0x08048439 <main+17>:   movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
0x08048441 <main+25>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
0x08048448 <main+32>:   call   0x8048404 <function>
0x0804844d <main+37>:   leave  
0x0804844e <main+38>:   ret
End of assembler dump.

(gdb) disass function
Dump of assembler code for function function:
0x08048404 <function+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048405 <function+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048407 <function+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp
0x0804840a <function+6>:    mov    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x08048410 <function+12>:   mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
0x08048413 <function+15>:   xor    %eax,%eax
0x08048415 <function+17>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
0x08048418 <function+20>:   xor    %gs:0x14,%eax
0x0804841f <function+27>:   je     0x8048426 <function+34>
0x08048421 <function+29>:   call   0x8048340 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
0x08048426 <function+34>:   leave  
0x08048427 <function+35>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

I am seeking answers for following things :

1. how the addressing is working , I mean (main+0) , (main+1), (main+3)
2. In the main, why is $0xfffffff0,%esp being used
3. In the function, why is %gs:0x14,%eax ,  %eax,-0xc(%ebp) being used.
4. If someone can explain , step by step happening, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For each of these points, you may want to explain what you think the answer is, and then if you are off it may be clarified.

Comment: no this is no homework..

Comment: For $0xfffffff0,%esp, I guess this is used for alignment purpose. Like the stack is 16bits aligned.

Comment: I am not sure about %gs:0x14,%eax. This is the main reason for posting the question

Comment: The `%gs` thing is related to thread-local storage, but I have no idea why it's popping up in such a simple program...

Comment: Oh, looks like you have some compiler options for stack overflow checking enabled.. Perhaps you're using a strange distro that's modified gcc's defaults?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Compile withh gcc -S -fverbose-asm to get a commented .S assembly file.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The reason for the "strange" addresses such as `main+0`, `main+1`, `main+3`, `main+6` and so on, is because each instruction takes up a variable number of bytes. For example:

```
main+0: push %ebp
```

is a one-byte instruction so the next instruction is at `main+1`. On the other hand,

```
main+3: and $0xfffffff0,%esp
```

is a three-byte instruction so the next instruction after that is at `main+6`.

And, since you ask in the comments why `movl` seems to take a variable number of bytes, the explanation for that is as follows.

Instruction length depends not only on the *opcode* (such as `movl`) but also the addressing modes for the *operands* as well (the things the opcode are operating on). I haven't checked specifically for your code but I suspect the

```
movl $0x1,(%esp)
```

instruction is probably shorter because there's no offset involved - it just uses `esp` as the address. Whereas something like:

```
movl $0x2,0x4(%esp)
```

requires everything that `movl $0x1,(%esp)` does, *plus* an extra byte for the offset `0x4`.

In fact, here's a debug session showing what I mean:

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

c:\pax> debug
-a
0B52:0100 mov word ptr [di],7
0B52:0104 mov word ptr [di+2],8
0B52:0109 mov word ptr [di+0],7
0B52:010E
-u100,10d
0B52:0100 C7050700      MOV     WORD PTR [DI],0007
0B52:0104 C745020800    MOV     WORD PTR [DI+02],0008
0B52:0109 C745000700    MOV     WORD PTR [DI+00],0007
-q
c:\pax> _
```

You can see that the second instruction with an offset is actually different to the first one without it. It's one byte longer (5 bytes instead of 4, to hold the offset) and actually has a different encoding `c745` instead of `c705`.

You can also see that you can encode the first and third instruction in two different ways but they basically do the same thing.

---

The `and $0xfffffff0,%esp` instruction is a way to force `esp` to be on a specific boundary. This is used to ensure proper alignment of variables. Many memory accesses on modern processors will be more efficient if they follow the alignment rules (such as a 4-byte value having to be aligned to a 4-byte boundary). Some modern processors will even raise a fault if you don't follow these rules.

After this instruction, you're guaranteed that `esp` is both less than or equal to its previous value *and* aligned to a 16 byte boundary.

---

The `gs:` prefix simply means to use the `gs` segment register to access memory rather than the default.

The instruction `mov %eax,-0xc(%ebp)` means to take the contents of the `ebp` register, subtract 12 (`0xc`) and then put the value of `eax` into that memory location.

---

Re the explanation of the code. Your `function` function is basically one big no-op. The assembly generated is limited to stack frame setup and teardown, along with some stack frame corruption checking which uses the afore-mentioned `%gs:14` memory location.

It loads the value from that location (probably something like `0xdeadbeef`) into the stack frame, does its job, then checks the stack to ensure it hasn't been corrupted.

Its job, in this case, is nothing. So all you see is the function administration stuff.

Stack set-up occurs between `function+0` and `function+12`. Everything after that is setting up the return code in `eax` and tearing down the stack frame, including the corruption check.

Similarly, `main` consist of stack frame set-up, pushing the parameters for `function`, calling `function`, tearing down the stack frame and exiting.

Comments have been inserted into the code below:

```
0x08048428 <main+0>:    push   %ebp                 ; save previous value.
0x08048429 <main+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp            ; create new stack frame.
0x0804842b <main+3>:    and    $0xfffffff0,%esp     ; align to boundary.
0x0804842e <main+6>:    sub    $0x10,%esp           ; make space on stack.

0x08048431 <main+9>:    movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)       ; push values for function.
0x08048439 <main+17>:   movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
0x08048441 <main+25>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
0x08048448 <main+32>:   call   0x8048404 <function> ; and call it.

0x0804844d <main+37>:   leave                       ; tear down frame.
0x0804844e <main+38>:   ret                         ; and exit.

0x08048404 <func+0>:    push   %ebp                 ; save previous value.
0x08048405 <func+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp            ; create new stack frame.
0x08048407 <func+3>:    sub    $0x28,%esp           ; make space on stack.
0x0804840a <func+6>:    mov    %gs:0x14,%eax        ; get sentinel value.
0x08048410 <func+12>:   mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)      ; put on stack.

0x08048413 <func+15>:   xor    %eax,%eax            ; set return code 0.

0x08048415 <func+17>:   mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax      ; get sentinel from stack.
0x08048418 <func+20>:   xor    %gs:0x14,%eax        ; compare with actual.
0x0804841f <func+27>:   je     <func+34>            ; jump if okay.
0x08048421 <func+29>:   call   <_stk_chk_fl>        ; otherwise corrupted stack.
0x08048426 <func+34>:   leave                       ; tear down frame.
0x08048427 <func+35>:   ret                         ; and exit.
```

---

I think the reason for the `%gs:0x14` may be evident from above but, just in case, I'll elaborate here.

It uses this value (a sentinel) to put in the current stack frame so that, should something in the function do something silly like write 1024 bytes to a 20-byte array created on the stack or, in your case:

```
char buffer1[5];
strcpy (buffer1, "Hello there, my name is Pax.");
```

then the sentinel will be overwritten and the check at the end of the function will detect that, calling the failure function to let you know, and then probably aborting so as to avoid any other problems.

If it placed `0xdeadbeef` onto the stack and this was changed to something else, then an `xor` with `0xdeadbeef` would produce a non-zero value which is detected in the code with the `je` instruction.

The relevant bit is paraphrased here:

```
          mov    %gs:0x14,%eax     ; get sentinel value.
          mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)   ; put on stack.

          ;; Weave your function
          ;;   magic here.

          mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax   ; get sentinel back from stack.
          xor    %gs:0x14,%eax     ; compare with original value.
          je     stack_ok          ; zero/equal means no corruption.
          call   stack_bad         ; otherwise corrupted stack.
stack_ok: leave                    ; tear down frame.
```

Comment: Thanks pax for the detailed answer. I still did not understand the logic behind, the increment in address, I mean, how the address increment is taking place , like main+0, main +1 , main+3, main+6, main+9 , main+17 and so on..

Comment: So referring to your point above,                                strcpy (buffer1, "Hello there, my name is Pax.");
Do you mean , it is a kind of bufferoverflow check, which the system is doing. So does that mean the buffer-overflow vulnerability may not be exploited here.

Comment: @Adi, yes, it's a stack overflow check, exactly as you describe. It doesn't _stop_ an exploit since a clever one would load the sentinel itself back into that location as part of its overflow strategy. It does however make it harder and reduces the chances of accidental corruption a great deal. And I've adjusted point 1 of my answer now that I understand the question better.

Comment: thanks pax..One comment I would like to make is, as the addressing depends on the no. of bytes an instruction takes. So I guess, movl is an 8 byte instruction , but                                                        0x08048431 <main+9>:    movl   $0x3,0x8(%esp)                       0x08048439 <main+17>:   movl   $0x2,0x4(%esp)
0x08048441 <main+25>:   movl   $0x1,(%esp)
0x08048448 <main+32>:   call   0x8048404 <function>                       movl after 25 should go to 33. 25+8.Just a bit confused about this.

Comment: @Adi, see the update to my answer. Basically, the `movl $0x1,(%esp)` is shorter than `movl $0x2,0x4(%esp)` because there's no offset involved in the former. The latter needs an extra byte to store the `0x4`.

Answer (score 3):

Pax has produced a definitive answer. However, for completeness, I thought I'd add a note on getting GCC itself to show you the assembly it generates.

The `-S` option to GCC tells it to stop compilation and write the assembly to a file. Normally, it either passes that file to the assembler or for some targets writes the object file directly itself.

For the sample code in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
}

void main() {
  function(1,2,3);
}
```

the command `gcc -S q3654898.c` creates a file named q3654898.s:

```
        .file   "q3654898.c"
        .text
.globl _function
        .def    _function;      .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_function:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $40, %esp
        leave
        ret
        .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
.globl _main
        .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;     .endef
_main:
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        subl    $24, %esp
        andl    $-16, %esp
        movl    $0, %eax
        addl    $15, %eax
        addl    $15, %eax
        shrl    $4, %eax
        sall    $4, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
        movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
        call    __alloca
        call    ___main
        movl    $3, 8(%esp)
        movl    $2, 4(%esp)
        movl    $1, (%esp)
        call    _function
        leave
        ret
```

One thing that is evident is that my GCC (gcc (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)) doesn't include the stack check code by default. I imagine that there is a command line option, or that if I ever got around to nudging my MinGW install up to a more current GCC that it could.

**Edit:** Nudged to do so by Pax, here's another way to get GCC to do more of the work.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Ross\My Documents\testing>gcc -Wa,-al q3654898.c
q3654898.c: In function `main':
q3654898.c:8: warning: return type of 'main' is not `int'
GAS LISTING C:\DOCUME~1\Ross\LOCALS~1\Temp/ccLg8pWC.s                   page 1


   1                            .file   "q3654898.c"
   2                            .text
   3                    .globl _function
   4                            .def    _function;      .scl    2;      .type
32;     .endef
   5                    _function:
   6 0000 55                    pushl   %ebp
   7 0001 89E5                  movl    %esp, %ebp
   8 0003 83EC28                subl    $40, %esp
   9 0006 C9                    leave
  10 0007 C3                    ret
  11                            .def    ___main;        .scl    2;      .type
32;     .endef
  12                    .globl _main
  13                            .def    _main;  .scl    2;      .type   32;
.endef
  14                    _main:
  15 0008 55                    pushl   %ebp
  16 0009 89E5                  movl    %esp, %ebp
  17 000b 83EC18                subl    $24, %esp
  18 000e 83E4F0                andl    $-16, %esp
  19 0011 B8000000              movl    $0, %eax
  19      00
  20 0016 83C00F                addl    $15, %eax
  21 0019 83C00F                addl    $15, %eax
  22 001c C1E804                shrl    $4, %eax
  23 001f C1E004                sall    $4, %eax
  24 0022 8945FC                movl    %eax, -4(%ebp)
  25 0025 8B45FC                movl    -4(%ebp), %eax
  26 0028 E8000000              call    __alloca
  26      00
  27 002d E8000000              call    ___main
  27      00
  28 0032 C7442408              movl    $3, 8(%esp)
  28      03000000
  29 003a C7442404              movl    $2, 4(%esp)
  29      02000000
  30 0042 C7042401              movl    $1, (%esp)
  30      000000
  31 0049 E8B2FFFF              call    _function
  31      FF
  32 004e C9                    leave
  33 004f C3                    ret

C:\Documents and Settings\Ross\My Documents\testing>
```

Here we see an output listing produced by the assembler. (Its name is `GAS`, because it is Gnu's version of the classic *nix assembler `as`. There's humor there somewhere.)

Each line has most of the following fields: a line number, an address in the current section, bytes stored at that address, and the source text from the assembly source file.
The addresses are offsets into that portion of each section provided by this module. This particular module only has content in the `.text` section which stores executable code. You will typically find mention of sections named `.data` and `.bss` as well. Lots of other names are used and some have special purposes. Read the manual for the linker if you really want to know.

Comment: `-fstack-protector`, I believe.  Some Linux distributions turn it on by default.

Comment: +1 just for "Pax has produced a definitive answer" :-) You may also want to add the fact that you can use `gcc -Wa,-al ...` to get the assembler to output a listing which includes the bytes generated as well as the source.

Comment: @Pax, ;-).  I'll try claiming with a straight face that I was going to, but MinGW messed up my output and then dinner was ready.... home cooked food takes precedence, naturally.

Comment: @Zack, that spelling doesn't work on my vintage 3.x GCC. It may be a GCC 4 thing. I'll check at the office where I have one sitting around.

Answer (score 3):

It will be better to try the **-fno-stack-protector** flag with gcc to disable the canary and see your results.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to add that for simple stuff, GCC's assembly output is often easier to read if you turn on a little optimization.  Here's the sample code again...

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
}

/* corrected calling convention of main() */
int main() {
   function(1,2,3);
   return 0;
}
```

this is what I get without optimization (OSX 10.6, gcc 4.2.1+Apple patches)

```
.globl _function
_function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ebx
    subl    $36, %esp
    call    L4
"L00000000001$pb":
L4:
    popl    %ebx
    leal    L___stack_chk_guard$non_lazy_ptr-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %edx
    movl    %edx, -12(%ebp)
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    leal    L___stack_chk_guard$non_lazy_ptr-"L00000000001$pb"(%ebx), %eax
    movl    (%eax), %eax
    movl    -12(%ebp), %edx
    xorl    (%eax), %edx
    je      L3
    call    ___stack_chk_fail
L3:
    addl    $36, %esp
    popl    %ebx
    leave
    ret
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $24, %esp
    movl    $3, 8(%esp)
    movl    $2, 4(%esp)
    movl    $1, (%esp)
    call    _function
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Whew, one heck of a mouthful!  But look what happens with `-O` on the command line...

```
    .text
.globl _function
_function:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    leave
    ret
.globl _main
_main:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Of course, you do run the risk of your code being rendered completely unrecognizable, especially at higher optimization levels and with more complicated stuff.  Even here, we see that the call to `function` has been discarded as pointless.  But I find that not having to read through dozens of unnecessary stack spills is generally more than worth a little extra scratching my head over the control flow.

Comment: If it's not even calling `function`, I wonder why it includes it in the executable?

Comment: If `function` were declared `static`, or if you'd compiled with `-fwhole-program`, it would have dropped it.  Otherwise it assumes that code outside the current translation unit may call `function`.

Comment: Oh right. But then couldn't the linker drop it? If it's linking an executable (not  a library) it knows which functions are being called from where. Does the linker have the capability of omitting code?

Comment: On Linux, the linker *can* do that with special options (`-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` at compile time, `-Wl,--gc-sections` at link time; with very recent GCC, `-flto` at compile time, `-flto -fwhole-program` at link time may have similar effects, I haven't tried it), but does not by default.  I don't know if the analogous feature exists on OSX.