# What is the meaning of each line of the assembly output of a C hello world?

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, x86

I ran gcc -S over this:

```
int main()
{
printf ("Hello world!");
}
```

and I got this assembly code:

```
        .file   "test.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello world!"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
        andl    $-16, %esp
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
        pushl   %ecx
        subl    $20, %esp
        movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
        call    printf
        addl    $20, %esp
        popl    %ecx
        popl    %ebp
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
        ret
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I am curious to understand this output. Can someone share some pointers in understanding this output, or if someone could mark comments against each of these lines/group of lines explaining what it does it would be great.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Here how it goes:

```
        .file   "test.c"
```

The original source file name (used by debuggers).

```
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "Hello world!"
```

A zero-terminated string is included in the section ".rodata" ("ro" means "read-only": the application will be able to read the data, but any attempt at writing into it will trigger an exception).

```
        .text
```

Now we write things into the ".text" section, which is where code goes.

```
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
```

We define a function called "main" and globally visible (other object files will be able to invoke it).

```
        leal    4(%esp), %ecx
```

We store in register `%ecx` the value `4+%esp` (`%esp` is the stack pointer).

```
        andl    $-16, %esp
```

`%esp` is slightly modified so that it becomes a multiple of 16. For some data types (the floating-point format corresponding to C's `double` and `long double`), performance is better when the memory accesses are at addresses which are multiple of 16. This is not really needed here, but when used without the optimization flag (`-O2`...), the compiler tends to produce quite a lot of generic useless code (i.e. code which could be useful in some cases but not here).

```
        pushl   -4(%ecx)
```

This one is a bit weird: at that point, the word at address `-4(%ecx)` is the word which was on top of the stack prior to the `andl`. The code retrieves that word (which should be the return address, by the way) and pushes it again. This kind of emulates what would be obtained with a call from a function which had a 16-byte aligned stack. My guess is that this `push` is a remnant of an argument-copying sequence. Since the function has adjusted the stack pointer, it must copy the function arguments, which were accessible through the old value of the stack pointer. Here, there is no argument, except the function return address. Note that this word will not be used (yet again, this is code without optimization).

```
        pushl   %ebp
        movl    %esp, %ebp
```

This is the standard function prologue: we save `%ebp` (since we are about to modify it), then set `%ebp` to point to the stack frame. Thereafter, `%ebp` will be used to access the function arguments, making `%esp` free again. (Yes, there is no argument, so this is useless for that function.)

```
        pushl   %ecx
```

We save `%ecx` (we will need it at function exit, to restore `%esp` at the value it had before the `andl`).

```
        subl    $20, %esp
```

We reserve 32 bytes on the stack (remember that the stack grows "down"). That space will be used to storea the arguments to `printf()` (that's overkill, since there is a single argument, which will use 4 bytes [that's a pointer]).

```
        movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
        call    printf
```

We "push" the argument to `printf()` (i.e. we make sure that `%esp` points to a word which contains the argument, here `$.LC0`, which is the address of the constant string in the rodata section). Then we call `printf()`.

```
        addl    $20, %esp
```

When `printf()` returns, we remove the space allocated for the arguments. This `addl` cancels what the `subl` above did.

```
        popl    %ecx
```

We recover `%ecx` (pushed above); `printf()` may have modified it (the call conventions describe which register can a function modify without restoring them upon exit; `%ecx` is one such register).

```
        popl    %ebp
```

Function epilogue: this restores `%ebp` (corresponding to the `pushl %ebp` above).

```
        leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
```

We restore `%esp` to its initial value. The effect of this opcode is to store in `%esp` the value `%ecx-4`. `%ecx` was set in the first function opcode. This cancels any alteration to `%esp`, including the `andl`.

```
        ret
```

Function exit.

```
        .size   main, .-main
```

This sets the size of the `main()` function: at any point during assembly, "`.`" is an alias for "the address at which we are adding things right now". If another instruction was added here, it would go at the address specified by "`.`". Thus, "`.-main`", here, is the exact size of the code of the function `main()`. The `.size` directive instructs the assembler to write that information in the object file.

```
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)"
```

GCC just loves to leave traces of its action. This string ends up as a kind of comment in the object file. The linker will remove it.

```
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

A special section where GCC writes that the code can accommodate a non-executable stack. This is the normal case. Executable stacks are needed for some special usages (not standard C). On modern processors, the kernel can make a non-executable stack (a stack which triggers an exception if someone tries to execute as code some data which is on the stack); this is viewed by some people as a "security feature" because putting code on the stack is a common way to exploit buffer overflows. With this section, the executable will be marked as "compatible with a non-executable stack" which the kernel will happily provide as such.

Comment: > `subl    $20, %esp`
> We reserve 32 bytes on the stack (remember that the stack grows "down").
Shouldn't it be 20 bytes instead of 32?

Comment: @Ragtime No because $20 is in written in base 16 (20 in base 16 is 32).

Answer (score 32):

Here is some supplement to `@Thomas Pornin`'s answer.

- `.LC0` local constant, e.g string literal.
- `.LFB0` local function beginning,
- `.LFE0` local function ending,

The suffix of these label is a number, and start from 0.

This is gcc assembler convention.

Answer (score 4):

```
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $20, %esp
```

these instructions don't compare in your c program, they're always executed at the beginning of every function (but it depends on compiler/platform)

```
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    printf
```

this block corresponds to your printf() call. the first instruction places on the stack its argument (a pointer to "hello world") then calls the function.

```
    addl    $20, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
```

these instructions are opposite to the first block, they're some sort of stack manipulation stuffs. always executed too