# Get literals from C++ binary

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, hardening

After compiling the C++ code

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    const char * c = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    int a = 1234567890;
    float tau = 6.28318530718;
    bool yes = true;
    const char ca[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
        0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

with

```
g++ a.cpp
```

one gets an `a.out` binary. Using [strings](https://linux.die.net/man/1/strings), it's possible to read the literal strings from the program, i.e.,

```
strings a.out | grep xyz
```

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Is it also possible to get the other literals? How?

Comment: As any [decent book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), class or tutorial should have taught you, all literal strings are really constant arrays of characters (including the null-terminator). They are usually stored together with the code and other constant data, but in a way to make them easy to detect and extract. Numeric literals are seldom stored separately. They can be stored directly in the location of the variable, or they can be copied using an assembler "move" instruction. Both ways which makes them very hard to detect and extract.

Comment: `readelf -p .rodata` could help

Comment: You can just disassemble your executable. Something [related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5329669/4165552)

Comment: `strings` "prints the printable character sequences that are at least 4 characters long [...] and are followed by an unprintable character". There is no useful such heuristic for determining whether something is a `char` or `int` or `float`, and if you change your array to `const char ca[] = { 0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x01};`, that will probably show up as a "string literal" even though it isn't.

Comment: @molbdnilo It does! Interesting.

Comment: @pptaszni "Just disassemble it" -- Is this as easy as it sounds? How would I go about extracting the numerical value `6.28318530718` for example?

Comment: Well no, I exaggerated bit. But first disassembling, and then running some heuristic search (e.g. looking for `.string`) can already give some good results. Didn't try with complex programs, but seems to work with some toy examples.

Comment: Numeric literals don't necessarily appear in the executable at all, other than as immediate operand values incorporated into the instruction.

Comment: @user207421 `int` literals _do_ appear in the binary, see my answer below. With `float`s, it seems more intricate.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer Your example shows assembly code, not the binary from an executable.

Comment: @user207421 I'm motivated by not wanting any literal info (easily) leak from the binary. One bad apple spoils the bunch.

Comment: @NicoSchlömer In which case you certainly won't be leaking assembly listings, *nu?*

Comment: @user207421 What does this mean?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Compiling

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    int a = 1234567890;
    return 0;
}
```

with `g++ a.cpp` and inspecting the output with

```
objdump -d a.out
```

gives

```
[...]
0000000000001119 <main>:
    1119:   55                      push   %rbp
    111a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    111d:   c7 45 fc d2 02 96 49    movl   $0x499602d2,-0x4(%rbp)
    1124:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    1129:   5d                      pop    %rbp
    112a:   c3                      ret
[...]
```

`0x499602d2` is the hex-representation of `1234567890`, so there's that.

The same with

```cpp
int main(void)
{
    const char ca[] = {
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07,
        0x08, 0x09, 0x0a, 0x0b, 0x0c, 0x0d, 0x0e, 0x0f,
        0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17,
        0x18, 0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f,
    };
    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
0000000000001139 <main>:
    1139:   55                      push   %rbp
    113a:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
    113d:   48 83 ec 30             sub    $0x30,%rsp
    1141:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
    1148:   00 00 
    114a:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
    114e:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
    1150:   48 b8 00 01 02 03 04    movabs $0x706050403020100,%rax
    1157:   05 06 07 
    115a:   48 ba 08 09 0a 0b 0c    movabs $0xf0e0d0c0b0a0908,%rdx
    1161:   0d 0e 0f 
    1164:   48 89 45 d0             mov    %rax,-0x30(%rbp)
    1168:   48 89 55 d8             mov    %rdx,-0x28(%rbp)
    116c:   48 b8 10 11 12 13 14    movabs $0x1716151413121110,%rax
    1173:   15 16 17 
    1176:   48 ba 18 19 1a 1b 1c    movabs $0x1f1e1d1c1b1a1918,%rdx
    117d:   1d 1e 1f 
    1180:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
    1184:   48 89 55 e8             mov    %rdx,-0x18(%rbp)
    1188:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
    118d:   48 8b 55 f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rdx
    1191:   64 48 2b 14 25 28 00    sub    %fs:0x28,%rdx
    1198:   00 00 
    119a:   74 05                   je     11a1 <main+0x68>
    119c:   e8 8f fe ff ff          call   1030 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
    11a1:   c9                      leave
    11a2:   c3                      ret
```

The char array is present in the four blocks 1150, 115a, 116c, and 1176.

Comment: The question is about the binary executable, not assembly code. The output you show does not demonstrate an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @user207421 Thanks for the reply. I don't fully understand what you mean. I have a binary and can extract info about literals in the source.

Comment: So show me where you extracted `0x499602d2` *from the binary.* Not the assembly listing.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. How do I not extract that "from the binary"? `a.out` is the binary, I run a `objdump` on it, and get the hex. Obviously there's something I'm missing here.