what does .LC* and .L* mean and what is its purpose in assembly?
(the asterixes in the title count as an incrementing number)
It looks like ".LC0" always has something to do with the main method and that ".LC*" always have something to do with strings but I don't know what the purpose of this is. Also what does ".L*" mean?
here some examples of what i mean.
I picked random sections of my code please tell me if that was wrong and i should have copypasted all my code on here
(code was generated by using following command on an 64bit intel CPU running windows: gcc main.c -S):
.LC0:
    .ascii "%x\0"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main

.LC3:
    .ascii "methodactivated \0"

.L3:
    movb    $120, currentPlayerInsignia(%rip)

.L18:
    nop
    addq    $32, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .section .rdata,"dr"


Nothing special, they are just label names. gcc seems to pick .L for code labels and .LC for data constants. I assume you know what labels are, but if not, they are just symbolic names to refer to particular addresses.

.LC is said to be "local constant" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/38290148/7916438), .L may simply mean "label".

Note when using gnu assembler and ELF format, .L is a prefix for local labels meaning they will not be in the symbol table.

See Local Symbol Names in the GAS manual https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html , @tevemadar .  Presumably the design intent is that .L in the symbol name stands for "local".  And yeah, GCC just auto-numbers, with .LC for constants and .L for others.
